# Making two UIScrollView's scroll as one, or transferring inertia between scroll views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

In our app you can build a question by searching for options from multiple third party sources. Most of these search results are displayed as full-width tableview cells, as their data suits that format (has a bunch of metadata text I can display next to the thumbnail).

In the case of images however, a collection view makes much more sense. But now I run into the problem of a vertical scrolling tableview containing a vertical scrolling collection view.

http://www.screencast.com/t/7Z48zkkW

I can make it work somewhat by capturing the `viewDidScroll` on the collection view and updating the parent scroll view instead at the appropriate offsets, but it only works well when the user is actively dragging the collection view.

```
self.collectionVC.scrollViewDidScroll = ^(UIScrollView *scrollView) {
    @strongify(self);
    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y < self.scrollingHeightOffset && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        CGFloat maxheight = MIN(self.scrollingHeightOffset, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, maxheight);
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 && self.tableView.contentOffset.y > -topGuide) {
        CGFloat minheight = MAX(-topGuide, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, minheight);
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    }
};
```

When 'flinging' the collection view, the scrolling stops abruptly, losing the inertia of the collection view. Touching the tableview to scroll has a different problem, as I'm not capturing that when it hits the end and scrolling the collection view instead.

Right now the collection view lives in a cell of the tableview, but it could also be a peer if necessary. I'm trying to determine the best way to make these two scrollviews appear as one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you did the right thing. `viewDidScroll` should be called several times even after user lift the finger and scroll view is returning to some position.

I use exact same approach to scroll couple scrollViews in sync when user is dragging one of them. Works perfectly.

You might want to check your calculation logic inside this method. See if it calls for all changes after user lift a finger, but you're positioning other scroll view in a wrong way.

Comment: Am I correct in resetting the offset on the child scrollview to 0 `scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);` when transferring it's movement to the parent? I feel like that's causing the inertia loss when flinging instead of actively dragging.

Comment: I'm not sure, since I can't really see how does it work and what are you trying to do. Try to log all values you're receiving inside `didScroll` and it will give you an idea of what's going on with the parent view - and from there you can deduct what you need to do with the child.

Answer (score 0):

I did this, let me know if it works for you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView1.panGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(didRecognizePanGesture:)];
    [self.tableView2.panGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(didRecognizePanGesture:)];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.selectedTableView == scrollView)
    {
        if (scrollView == self.tableView1)
        {
            self.tableView2.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
        }
        else if (scrollView == self.tableView2)
        {
            self.tableView1.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
        }
    }
}

- (void)didRecognizePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        if (self.selectedTableView != nil) //this is gonna make stop the previous scrollView
        {
            [self.selectedTableView setContentOffset:self.selectedTableView.contentOffset animated:NO];
        }
        self.selectedTableView = (UITableView*)gesture.view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your tableviews the same height here?

Comment: yes, but if you have different heights, you probably should set the contentOffset proportional to the height or contentSize.